# unable to run executable jar file by double clicking on it with Amazon Corretto 8

Tags: java, corretto

unable to run executable jar file by double clicking on it with Amazon Corretto 8

I have uninstalled Oracle java 8 from my machine (windows 10) and installed amazon corretto 8. since then i am unable to run the executable jar file by double clicking on it. I am able to run the executable jar file using CMD (java -jar Myjar.jar) . I have tried following to fix the issue.

1) associating the default program to open the jar files.

2) editing the jar_auto_file registry.

3) creating the jar file from CMD (jar -cvfm AwtExample.jar manifest.txt com/abc/awt/*.class )

4) creating the executable jar from the Eclipse.

I am not sure if this the limitation of the amazon corretto 8 or issue with windows 10.

I am looking for a solution which should run the executable jar by just double clicking on it, without changing the windows registry.

Answer (score 2):

What you ask — i.e. "run the executable jar by just double clicking on it, without changing the windows registry" — is not technically possible, as all file associations are stored in the Windows Registry. Even when you do it through Explorer. The Oracle installation script creates the necessary file type associations in the Registry. The current release of Corretto unfortunately doesn't do that. You can use the following CMD commands to establish the association:

```
assoc .jar=jarfile
assoc jarfile=Executable Jar File
ftype jarfile="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_192\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

(Make sure you specify the correct directory.)

Comment: Can you explain why the `assoc jarfile=Executable Jar File` command is needed?

Comment: @Slaw it supplies a description which is displayed in the "Type" column of Windows Explorer. This description is the same as the one used by Oracle when its JDK (1.8 or earlier) is installed.